# Java- How can I get an array of numbers through a GUI

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface

I am trying to build something which needs an array of numbers entered by the user. The problem is, I don't know how to do this. I was thinking about using a JTextField but they are in string format not numbers... (I am struggling to word this out :\   ) The textfield's getText method is designed to get a String not an array. Can someone please help me? I will be EXTREMELY grateful if you do as I have been trying for ages :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The textfield's getText method is designed to get a String not an
>   array

Yes Java has `String` as it's first Love.

Let me give you an Idea how can you do it.

As you have mentioned you need to use `JTextField`

- Enter Numbers Using Separator (Ex. 1,2,5,60)
- Retrive it and Store it as `String`
- Use `split()` function to get all numbers in `String` array.
- Use `Integer.parseInt("1")` method to convert String to int.

---

For Example:

```
String str=jt.getText();//JtextField Has text as 1,3,4,55,10
String strA[]=new String[5];
strA=str.split(",")
int intA[]=new int[5];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
intA[i]=Integer.parseInt(strA[i]);
}
```

*NOTE: It will only work for specific numbers say here I am passing 5 but if you pass 6 than it will give you IndexOutOfBound Exception.So in that case it would be better to use ArrayList*

Comment: Beat me to the answer by seconds: +1.

Comment: @MartinDinov Yes few seconds!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response but I don't understand how to write the Integer.parseInt("1") as I am not sure what you meant by the argument "1" you put in. I wrote this: JTextField numbers = new JTextField(20);
  String numsAsString = numbers.getText();
  String[] numsStringArray = numsAsString.split(numsAsString);
  Integer.parseInt(numsStringArray); But I get a red line under parseInt. Can you help me?

Comment: Ok I think I'm just being stupid now.. (I apologize for this) But it's still not working. I made a for loop to do what you said (Sorry if this is hard to read.. I don't know how to insert a code snippet without making a new question) String numsAsString = numberstxt.getText();
  
  //split it everywhere there is a ,
  String[] stringSplit = numsAsString.split(",");
  int numValue = max - 1;
  double[] numbers = new double[numValue];
  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
   
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringSplit[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(numbers); But it still throws an error...

Comment: Say the textfield is = to "4.5,7,8,9" or something. I have now changed it to: numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(stringSplit[i]); As I realised it was changing it to an int but that still didn't do anything :(

Comment: What is confusing for you ?And yes you better parse it to double if you want user to enter floating point numbers.What kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Okay No problem that will be more efficient but logic will remain same.

Comment: How do I split an arraylist like I did with the array? Or should I ask this as another question?

Comment: You need to use `split` method but this method returns Array only not ArrayList.So you need to decide I will suggest you to go for Array if your Input length is fix .

Comment: Could you not just get the array length in a vairiable and then pass it into the intA[]'s capacity. Example: int cap = array.Size(); intA[cap]? Would that not work?